# How to convert a string parameter into Object type in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, parameters, type-conversion, prototype

I am making a function in the Data-Type "*Object*",
Code:

```
Object.exists = function(obj){
if(typeof(obj)==="object"){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Its purpose is to check whether an object exists or not. Everything works fine if the object entered exists, but if I try to check an object which does not exist(I am trying to develop a function and am currently checking it), it throws an error. The code to check and the error msg:

```
Object.exists(demo); //Note: demo is not an object
//Error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: demo is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:15
```

and if I try to add `demo` in quotes, then it does not work and shows false even if I try to add an existing object. If I try

```
if(typeof(obj)==="object"){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

the code above without the function and the object doesn't exist, no error is thrown.
So I tried to work out my dumb brain and thought that can I use `eval()`, but I don't think so. Is there any other way I can convert the parameter(even if it is a string) into an object for the `if` statement?

Comment: If `demo` identifier is not *declared* yet, `Object.exists(demo)` will throw an error when it evaluates `demo`. Why do you need a separate function? Why not just use `let exists = typeof demo === 'object'`.

Comment: Uh, when you say "it doesn't exist", do you actually mean that's an undeclared variable? Because you've opened a whole can of worms there. 1. You *cannot* pass an undeclared variable anywhere. Any reading of undeclared variable is an error, so `foo(undeclared)` will throw an error before even `foo` is invoked. Only `typeof foo` will not error 2. If you need to check for undeclared variables *so much* that you need a helper function, you're doing something very wrong. You shouldn't have undeclared variables. You should know for certain when something would exist.

Comment: @adiga, I am creating a library(Or am trying to), so this type of function is gonna help.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes it is not declared, that is why I need to know how to convert a string into an object.

Comment: And I'm telling you that *having to do that* is indicative of a bigger problem you have. The correct solution here is to not be in this situation.

Comment: @VLAZ I want the function to check whether an object exists or not.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. And it's a bad idea. Read my first comment, point 1.

Comment: @VLAZ You never know what situation you may be put into, but this function has a purpose. Sites with Google Adsense have an object named `adsbygoogle` with an integer `pauseAdRequests` and if you have an AdBlocker, the value of `pauseAdequest` gets set to 1, otherwise, it is 0. So for a library, if someone wants to check if there is an AdBlocker, this can help in it. I have verified it myself, and you can too. Just go to https://w3schools.com/html/default.asp and in the console, type and see the answer yourself.

Comment: I don't want to repeat yet again what I've written in the fist comment. All the relevant information is there. But here it goes - you ***CANNOT*** pass an undeclared variable to a function because ***reading*** an undeclared variable is an error. Making a function that tries to verify if a variable is declared or not cannot work. Only `typeof` will not throw an error. Which you wouldn't help in a function because you cannot *call* that function with an undeclared variable. You'd get an error before the call is ever made. Converting string to an object does not help with this fundamental issue.

Comment: ok :( I will not ask more \*cries*

Answer (score 1):

I just found out the answer,
used `eval()` and it worked!
The code:

```
Object.exists = function(obj){
    var type = eval("typeof("+obj+")");
    console.log(type);
}
```

When you try an object which exists, it logs `object`, but if you try anything other, it logs it's type.